# Is there a way to capture HTML5 video events on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, html

I have my standard video tag which is playing fine in Chrome;

```
<video width="x" height="y" src="video.mp4"></video>
```

The video itself plays fine on the iPhone, however, is there no way to listen for events? Any kind of event? I'd like to use the 'ended' event, but even a 'click' or 'play' would be helpful!

The standard

```
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  alert('this adds nothing');
}, false);
```

doesn't work at all, and nor can I track a click event (In the same way) on the video tag.

If not, would it be possible to perhaps add a transparent  over the top of the video, track a click event to that as normal but then fire the play event for the video so that the video loads in the separate window as normal?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me on an iphone/ipad/safari/chrome

> ```
>        $('#video_1').bind("ended",videoFinished);
> ```
>
> function videoFinished(e) {
>   console.log("im done); }

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from [Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Sequential Movies</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       // listener function changes src
       function myNewSrc() {
          var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
          myVideo.src="http://homepage.mac.com/qt4web/sunrisemeditations/myMovie.m4v";
          myVideo.load();
          myVideo.play();
        }

       // function adds listener function to ended event -->

        function myAddListener(){
         var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
         myVideo.addEventListener('ended',myNewSrc,false);
        }
   </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="myAddListener()">
      <video controls
        src="http://homepage.mac.com/qt4web/sunrisemeditations/A-chord.m4v"
       >
      </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I've tried - my example is actually injected via JS, but.. academic - and that event does not fire on the iPhone.

Comment: I can confirm the above code does fire for the iPad... don't know if that will help at all.

Comment: That is helpful - thanks!

So does that mean it won't work at all on the iPhone? Does anyone know? Can anyone think of some kind of workaround? Basically I need to modify the DOM after the video either ends or, I suppose, once the video is playing (Since it opens in a new window).